# Windows 8 and GNSS location provider, read state (disabled / enabled)

Tags: gps, windows-10, windows-8.1

Does anyone know how to check (read) information whether in windows 8/8.1/10 GNSS location provider is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and set gnss state in system register. Register key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\Misc\BcmGnssRadioManager
```

Value name: currRadioState, available value data:

- DEVICE_RADIO_STATE_RADIO_ON = 0
- DEVICE_RADIO_STATE_SW_RADIO_OFF = 1
- DEVICE_RADIO_STATE_HW_RADIO_OFF  = 2
- DEVICE_RADIO_STATE_SW_HW_RADIO_OFF = 3
- DEVICE_RADIO_STATE_HW_RADIO_ON_UNCONTROLLABLE  = 4
- DEVICE_RADIO_STATE_RADIO_INVALID = 5
- DEVICE_RADIO_STATE_HW_RADIO_OFF_UNCONTROLLABLE = 6